# Cloudant Sorting on a nullable field

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I want to sort on a field lets say **name** which is indexed in Cloudant DB. I am getting all the documents both which has this name field and which doesn't by using the index without sort . But when i try to sort with the name **field** I am not getting the documents which doesn't have this name field in the doc.

Is there any way to do this by using the query indexes. I want all the documents in sorted order which doesn't have the **name** field too.

For Example :
Below are some documents:

```
{
 "_id": 1234,
 "classId": "abc",
 "name": "Happa"
}
{
  "_id": 12345,
  "classId": "abc",
  "name": "Prasanth"
}
{
  "_id": 123456,
  "classId": "abc",
}
```

Below is the Query what i am trying to execute:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "classId": "abc",
    "name" :{
      "or" : [
        {"$exists": true},{"$exists": false}
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [{ "classId": "asc" }, { "name": "asc" }],
  "use_index": "idx-classId_name"
},
```

I am expecting all the documents to be returned in a sorted order including the document which doesn't have that **name** field.

Comment: It would help if you specified what you mean by "index" in this case. Is this a standard map-reduce view, or a Cloudant Search (aka Lucene) index, or a Cloudant Query index? It's not clear to me what you're asking -- you want documents sorted by a specific field, inlcuding those that don't have the field? How do you expect to sort documents on a field that doesn't exist? Give some example documents, and tell us the ordering you expect.

Comment: @xpqz sorry for not being clear. Added the necessary  info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query makes no sense to me as it stands. You're requesting a listing of documents which either have, or don't have a specific field (meaning every document), and expecting to sort those on this field that may or may not exist. Such an order isn't defined out of the box.

I'd remove the name clause from the selector, sorting only on the classId field which appear in every document, and then do the secondary partial ordering on the client side, so you can decide how you intend to mix in the documents without the name field with those that have it.

Another solution is to use a view instead of a Cloudant Query index. I've not tested this, but hopefully the intent is clear:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc && doc.classId) {
        var name = doc.name || "[notfound]";
        emit(doc.classId+"-"+name, 1);
    }
}
```

which will key the docs on "classId-name" and for docs with no name, a specified sentinel value.

Querying the view should return the documents lexicographically ordered on this compound key (which you can reverse with a query parameter if you wish).